# JSF2 and JPA Validator is not working although i have a<h:message

Tags: validation, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I have a Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 546951187473649176L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 25)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z ]*", message = " wroooooong")
    private String name;

    /** some setters and getters **/
}
```

I have a UserController.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4210819542193607967L;

    @EJB
    private UserProvider userProvider;

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initNewUser() {
        user = new User();
    }

    private User user;

    public void registerUser() throws ValidatorException  {
        try {
            userProvider.registerUser(new User(),user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));

        }
    }

    private String name;
    /** some setters and getters **/

}
```

The UserProvider looks like this:

```
@RequestScoped
@Stateful
public class UserProvider {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void registerUser (User newUser, String name) throws Exception {
        try {
            newUser.setName(name);
            entityManager.persist(newUser);
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

and, finally my register.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{userController.name}" required="true"  />
    <h:message id="register_name_error" for="name" errorClass="invalid"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{userController.registerUser()}" id="submit" value="send" />
</h:form>
```

When i enter something to short in the name field, i got this in my stack:

```
 javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [de.liedl.bachelor.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='muss zwischen 3 und 25 liegen', propertyPath=accountName, rootBeanClass=class de.demotest.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]
```

but the error is never thrown back to my `<h:message`
What is wrong?
I downloaded a demo-application, where it worked totally easy, but this was little bit different, without provider and controller and model, it was just the the model and a mix-class...

I also tried this with just throw exception and with and without try catch

which Validator do i need in the UserProvider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the field to a property of the model, not to a property of the controller.

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{userController.user.name}" required="true"  />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, throwing a `ValidatorException` inside an action method makes no sense. You have 2 options:

1. Let it go so that it end up in container's default error page or a custom one definied in `web.xml`.
2. Create and add a faces message yourself by `FacesContext#addMessage()`.

Further I also wonder how it's useful to have a `@Stateful` service in this particular case. It could be as good just `@Stateless`. That `@RequestScoped` on an EJB is completely unnecessary and only confusing. That whole `try-catch` and `throws Exception` in the service method is also completely unnecessary. That `@Inject` won't work at all in side a `@ManagedBean`. The one inside the EJB must be `@PersistenceContext` instead. You're completely mixing JSF/CDI/EJB annotations. Please be very careful with this.

Comment: thanks Balus. 
but what you mean with: @Inject ist not working in my Controller? you mean the `@Inject EntityManager em;` i have some functions in my controller, where it looks like it is working? - also the EJB (UserProvider) looks like its working

Comment: `@Inject` only works in `@Named` classes. It's part of CDI not JSF or EJB.

Comment: and if I do in the model something like:  `@Column(unique=true)` it is not send to my jsf... but i get `Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.USER(EMAIL)"; SQL statement`

Comment: That's not from bean validation. That's from JPA. Catch the exception in your action method and add an error faces message. Or implement a `Validator` which checks the uniqueness beforehand. Or, better, do both.